# Site Performance: rel=canonical vs redirect 301

Tags: redirect, seo, canonical-link, canonicalization

From [this page on the blog of Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/rel-canonical-html-head/), he says that `rel=canonical` should be a secondary choice if you can't use a 301 redirect. Is there any performance issue with using a 301 redirect instead of a `rel=canonical`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, the performance difference is negligible.  There are more steps involved in the implementation of 301 redirects, so `rel=canonical` might perform slightly better.  The extra steps are typically executed very quickly and should not add any noticeable delay or strain on server resources.

### rel=canonical

1. User makes a request for /non-canonical.html
2. Server looks up canonical URL: /canonical.html
3. Server builds a page that includes the canonical tag and sends it to the user

### 301 Redirect

1. User makes a request for /non-canonical.html
2. Server looks up canonical URL: /canonical.html
3. Server issues a 301 redirect to the canonical URL.
4. User's browser automatically makes a second request for /canonical.html
5. Server discovers that this request is for a canonical URL.
6. Server builds a page and sends it to the user.