# Permanent redirect issue after database corrupted

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-301

Here is the situation: I took over a WordPress project, which turned out to have a corrupted database (wp_terms table missing among other problems) for a while. While all posts appeared to be assigned to a category, they actually weren't!

Result: A ton of 404s we're created because url/category/something/post-slug was actually only accesible via url/post-slug. Ouch!

There were a lot of content changes in the past and after the SEO company discovered the 404s (after months), they ask me to set 301s for all posts.

I have now completely rebuild the database locally, imported posts/pages etc. and would like to assign the posts back to its categories. What's the best way to do so? I assume I cannot simply remove the permanent redirects because Google probably has indexed the pages already!?

Should I basically set permanent redirects for the permanent redirects?

For some reason I cannot believe its best practice but lets see what you guys think!

Answer (score 1):

Its really bad practice to use chains of 301 redirects, but sure it kind of happens some times. If you want you can try the other way around and use the canonical option or 302 redirects so if you need to do another redirect in the future not to bug the chain with a third level of 301 redirect. Here is a post that compares the two ways : 
[Site Performance: rel=canonical vs redirect 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916949/site-performance-rel-canonical-vs-redirect-301)

Comment: Thanks for the link! The canonical option is only for when you have two pages but you want Google to use the "preffered" one, so you avoid the issue of duplicate content, correct? The thing is that I don't really have an issue with duplicate content but with the pages moved from one to another location, and now I'd love to move it back to its former location. Does that make any sense?